# cohomology ring of Lie algebras: multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie $R$-algebra, then the [Chevalley-Eilenberg complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology) defines the cohomology modules $H^k(\mathfrak{g})$. If $H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})=\bigoplus_kH^k(\mathfrak{g})$, then the diagonal map $\mu\!:\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{g}\!\times\!\mathfrak{g}$ and zero map $\iota\!:\mathfrak{g}\!\longrightarrow\!0$ induce maps $$\mu^\ast\!:H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})\!\otimes\!H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})\!=\!H^\ast(\mathfrak{g}\!\times\!\mathfrak{g})\longrightarrow H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})~~~\text{ and  }~~~\iota^\ast\!:R\!=\!H^\ast(0)\!\longrightarrow\!H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})$$ that make $H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})$ and associative unital graded-commutative $R$-algebra, right?

What worries me here is that there is no mention of Lie brackets $[-,-]$ in this multiplication: they only appear in the boundaries of the cochain complex.

Is there a nice example of Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\mathfrak{g}\!\cong\!\mathfrak{h}$ and $H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})\!\cong\!H^\ast(\mathfrak{h})$ as modules, but $H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})\!\ncong\!H^\ast(\mathfrak{h})$ as algebras?

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138343/cohomology-ring-of-abelian-lie-algebra#1138364) for an explicit formula for the diagonal map.

Comment: That the formula for the product does not depend directly on the bracket is quite irrelevant, really. You should not worry about it. The formula for the cup product in singular cohomology of spaces, for example, does not depend on the space, and this carries on to pretty much all cohomology theories.

Comment: As for your request for an example: no, there is no simple example, simply because thre are not many simple examples of cases where the cohomology algebra can be determined easily. Do you know any?

Comment: No, I don't know any, but that doesn't mean much. In Weibel's book, I didn't find any examples either.

Comment: Well, I am telling you :-) It is quite non trivial to describe the algebra structure. Even finding the dimension of cohomology is a highly non-trivial problem.

Comment: You should google for the list of 3-dimensional Lie algebras and compute explicitly the cohomology and the cup product for all of them.

Comment: Ok, will do. Question: if $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian with basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, then we should have $H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})\cong\Lambda_R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ where $\deg x_i\!=\!1$, but my computations disagree. $\Lambda^k\mathfrak{g}$ has basis $\{e_\sigma; \sigma\!\subseteq\![n],|\sigma|\!=\!k\}$ and $(\Lambda^k\mathfrak{g})^\ast$ has dual basis $\{\chi_\sigma; \sigma\!\subseteq\![n],|\sigma|\!=\!k\}$. But $\mu^\ast:(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'})=\chi_{\sigma,\sigma'}\mapsto\chi_{\sigma,\sigma'}\!\!\!\circ\!\mu$ which sends $e_\tau\!\mapsto\!\begin{cases}1; \sigma=\tau=\sigma'\\0\end{cases}$.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question and be more explicit about what your problem is :-)

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you!