# cohomology ring of abelian Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

This is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138207/cohomology-ring-of-lie-algebras-multiplication).

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie $R$-algebra with module basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ and zero brackets. Then in the Chevalley (co)chain complex, $\Lambda^k\mathfrak{g}$ has basis $\{e_\sigma; \sigma\!\subseteq\![n],|\sigma|\!=\!k\}$ where $e_{\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}}\!=\!e_{i_1}\!\wedge\!\ldots\!\wedge\!e_{i_k}$ and $(\Lambda^k\mathfrak{g})^\ast$ has dual basis $\{\chi_\sigma; \sigma\!\subseteq\![n],|\sigma|\!=\!k\}$ where $\chi_\sigma(e\tau)={\small\begin{cases}1;\; \sigma=\tau\\0;\;\text{otherwise}\end{cases}}$. All (co)boundary operators are zero, so $H^\ast(\mathfrak{g}\!\times\!\mathfrak{g})$ has basis $\{(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'}); \sigma,\sigma'\!\subseteq\![n]\}$.

The multiplication induced by the diagonal map is $\mu^\ast:(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'})\mapsto(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'})\!\circ\!\mu$ which sends $e_\tau\!\mapsto\!{\small\begin{cases}1;\; \sigma=\tau=\sigma'\\0;\;\text{otherwise}\end{cases}}$.  What is the presentation of $H^\ast(\mathfrak{g})$ (as a quotient of $\Lambda_R[x_1,\ldots,x_N]$)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by «$(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'})\circ\mu$»?

Comment: $(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'})$ is a dual basis vector of $\Lambda^k(\mathfrak{g}\!\times\!\mathfrak{g})$, i.e. a map that sends $(e_\tau,e_\tau')\mapsto\delta_{\sigma,\tau}\!\cdot\!\delta_{\sigma',\tau'}$, so $(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'})\!\circ\!\mu$ sends $e_\tau\mapsto(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{\sigma'})(e_\tau,e_\tau)=\delta_{\sigma,\tau}\!\cdot\!\delta_{\sigma',\tau}$.

Comment: Well, that is your problem. That is not how the product is computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $C(\mathfrak g)$ for the Chevalley-Eilenberg resolution of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. The diagonal map $D:\mathfrak g\to \mathfrak g\times \mathfrak g$ is a Lie algebra map, and one can use is to construct a morphism of complexes $D_*:C(\mathfrak g)\to C(\mathfrak g\times \mathfrak g)$.

On the other hand, there is a map $C(\mathfrak g\times \mathfrak g)\to C(\mathfrak g)\otimes C(\mathfrak g)$. The composition of this with $D_*$ gives a map $$C(\mathfrak g)\to C(\mathfrak g)\otimes C(\mathfrak g).$$ If you apply $\hom_{\mathfrak g}(-,k)$ in all places, this gives a map $$\Delta:C(\mathfrak g)^*\otimes C(\mathfrak g)^*\to C(\mathfrak g)^*$$ which induces the cup product. Notice that my $C(\mathfrak g)^*$ is your $(\Lambda \mathfrak g)^*$.

---

In concrete terms, the map $\Delta$ is given by $$(\Delta(f,g))(x_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_{p+q})=\sum_\pi \mathrm{sgn}\pi f(x_{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge x_{i_p})g(x_{i_{p+1}}\wedge\ldots\wedge x_{i_{p+q}})$$ when $f$ and $g$ are a $p$-cocycle and a $q$-cocycle, respectively, and the sign in each term comes from the signature of the permutation of the $x_i$s it involves, and the sum is over permutations $\pi=(i_1,\dots,i_{p+q})$ of $(1,\dots,p+q)$ such that $i_1<\cdots<i_p$ and $i_{p+1}<\cdots<i_{p+q}$ (which we call *shuffles*). To get at this formula you need to make everything above explicit, of course.

---

Using this formula, it is easy to see that in the abelian case $\chi_\sigma\smile\chi_{\sigma'}$ is zero if $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are not disjoint, and $\pm1$ times $\chi_{\sigma\cup\sigma'}$ in case they are disjoint, with the sign coming from a permutation etc. The isomorphism from the cohomology algebra to the exterior algebra is more or less obvious when you write things out.

Comment: Hmm, this was unexpected! Let me think on it a bit...

Comment: You can fix my typos, you know :-)

Comment: Does your formula for $\smile$ appear anywhere in the literature?

Comment: @Leon, It certainly does, but I could not point you to a specific appearance. The cohomology of the abelian Lie algebra is the same thing as an Ext for a polynomial ring, for example, and that shows up pretty much everywhere in commutative algebra.